# next.js, how to import different modules depending on environment

Tags: node.js, typescript, next.js, next.js14

I have two modules 'web,ts' and 'node.ts' with identical interfaces. The first is meant to run on both the client side and the edge environment while the other relies on node:crypto.

I would like to have a single module (dyna.ts) that acts as a front for both that I can import from anywhere in the project without worrying about the current environment.

I have attempted this but the compiler always crashes, as an example my last attempt:

```
import webBox from "./web";

type CryptoBox = {
  hash: (data: string, salt: string, ...moreSalt: string[]) => Promise<string>;
  random: (range: bigint) => bigint;
};

let _hash: CryptoBox["hash"] | undefined;
let _random: CryptoBox["random"] | undefined;

if (typeof crypto === "undefined" && process.release.name === "node") {
  try {
    let box = require("./node");
    _hash = box.hash;
    _random = box.random;
  } catch (error) {
    if (typeof webBox.hash !== "undefined") _hash = webBox.hash;
    if (typeof webBox.random !== "undefined") _random = webBox.random;
  }
} else {
  if (typeof webBox.hash !== "undefined") _hash = webBox.hash;
  if (typeof webBox.random !== "undefined") _random = webBox.random;
}

if (typeof _hash === "undefined") throw new Error("no hash function available");

if (typeof _random === "undefined")
  throw new Error("no random function available");

export const hash = _hash;
export const random = _random;
```

note1: The type `CryptoBox` is the type of the default export of both './node.ts' and './web.ts'

note2: Checking `typeof window === undefined` is useless here as the edge runtime lacks a window but cannot use node:crypto, and even if it did work `require("./node")` crashes the compiler when wrapped in a `if(false)`.

note3: `(await import()).default` crashes the same way `require()`

Hopefully this is possible so I don't have to maintain 3 identical modules (except for what they import) to do basic verification on data passed around by the client middleware and node server.

ps: the error message:

```
node:crypto
Module build failed: UnhandledSchemeError: Reading from "node:crypto" is not handled by plugins (Unhandled scheme).
Webpack supports "data:" and "file:" URIs by default.
You may need an additional plugin to handle "node:" URIs.
Import trace for requested module:
node:crypto
./src/lib/crypto/node.ts
./src/lib/crypto/dyna.ts
./src/lib/server_only/auth/login.ts
```

pps: (for Mike) the older variant I tried first:

```
type CryptoBox={
    hash: (data: string, salt: string, ...moreSalt: string[]) => Promise<string>;
    random: (range: bigint) => bigint;
}
let box:CryptoBox;
try{
    box=require("./node");
}catch(error){
    box=require("./web");
}
export const hash=box.hash;
export const random=box.random;
```

Comment: Don't mix `import` and `require`. Use the dynamic import, but note that don't you have any default exports, so `(await import(...)).default` _can't_ work. Import the actual named exports, e.g. `const { random, hash } = await import(...);`. And note that you don't need to export two consts just to get the right names, simply use export aliasing: `export { _hash as hash, _random as random };`

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans the default exports exist in the two modules 'web,ts' and 'node.ts', I was referring to using (await import(...))default as a direct replacement for require() in the line directly after "try{" 

As far as the aliasing goes; good to know.

Comment: Then at least change the code (back?) to using `import` everywhere, because having import and require in the same file is a guaranteed error, and you want to have as little erroneous code in your post so that folks can focus on the one thing that goes wrong. The error is kind of already telling you what's wrong: you're running webpack, but you haven't told it what `node:...` modules are. If you're bundling, you're going to need different webpack configs for web vs. node because webpack needs to know which target it's bundling for.

Answer (score 0):

This the workaround I'm now using as an answer until I can get something less fragile.

Instead of importing the correct module 'dyna.ts' instead provides an object (cryptoState) that can be given the correct crypto module by importing (for its side effects alone) a different module (provideNode.ts or provideWeb.ts) that will ensure any other module importing the cryptoState object will use the desired crypto functions (just remember never to point directly at the functions instead use: `cryptoState.core.fuctionName(args)`).

For forwards compatibility with a 'dyna.ts' that actually works as desired the needed crypto functions are available as arrow functions that call the functions inside cryptoState. (This also makes it backwards compatible with modules written before I ran into the problems being solved here.)

dyna.ts:

```
import { CryptoBox } from "../types";
import box from './web'; //for fallback purposes, this is expected to fail internally and respond with {hash:undefined;random:undefined}
class CryptoState{
    private _givenCore:false|"node"|"web"|"unspecified"|"webFallback";
    private _coreWrites:bigint;
    private _core:undefined|CryptoBox;
    constructor(){
        this._givenCore=false;
        this._coreWrites=0n;
        this._core=undefined;
    }
    get givenCore():false|"node"|"web"|"unspecified"|"webFallback"{
        return this._givenCore;
    }
    set givenCore(arg:"node"|"web"){
        console.log("setting givenCore to:",arg)
        if (this._givenCore==="unspecified"||this._givenCore==="webFallback") this._givenCore=arg;
        else if (this._givenCore===false) throw new Error("CryptoState will not set givenCore string before having a core object");
        else if (this._givenCore!==arg) throw new Error("CryptoState will not set givenCore string to something contradicting prior givenCore string")
    }
    get core(){
        if (this._givenCore && this._core) return this._core;
        if (box.hash && box.random) {//todo keep updated
            this._givenCore="webFallback";
            this._core=box as CryptoBox;
            this._coreWrites++
            return this._core;
        }else throw new Error("CryptoState core access attempted prior to initialization without fallback");
    }
    set core(arg:CryptoBox){
        console.log("setting core");
        if (this._core===undefined) this._core=arg;
        this._coreWrites++
        if (this._givenCore===false) this._givenCore="unspecified";
    }
    setCore(core:CryptoBox,envStr:"node"|"web"){
        this.core=core;
        this.givenCore=envStr;
    }
}
export const cryptoState=new CryptoState();//! do not point directly at its functions instead keep using cryptoState.core.functionName as the value of core may be replaced
export const hash=(data: string, salt: string, ...moreSalt: string[])=>{
    return cryptoState.core.hash(data,salt,...moreSalt);
}
export const random=(range:bigint)=>{
    return cryptoState.core.random(range);
}
```

provideNode.ts:

```
import { cryptoState } from "./dyna";
import core from "./node";
cryptoState.setCore(core,"node");
export default cryptoState;
```

provideWeb.ts:

```
import { CryptoBox } from "../types";
import { cryptoState } from "./dyna";
import core from "./web";
cryptoState.setCore(core as CryptoBox,"node");
export default cryptoState;
```

To ensure that having `import box from './web'` as an available fallback in 'dyna.ts' 'web.ts' is written to fail without emitting an error:

web.ts:

```
import { CryptoBox } from "../types";
//* run when node is unavailable (edge & client side)
const box:Partial<CryptoBox>={};
try{
    if (typeof crypto === "undefined") throw new Error("lacking web crypto");
    async function hash(data:string,salt:string,...extraSalt:string[]):Promise<string> 
    async function hash(...data:string[]):Promise<string>{
        ...omitted function content
    }
    box.hash=hash;
    function random(range:bigint){
        ...omitted function content
    }
    box.random=random;
}catch(error){
    console.warn(error);
    box.hash=undefined;
    box.random=undefined;
}
export default box;
```

And finally 'node.ts' remains unchanged but for compleatnesses sake:

node.ts:

```
const _crypto:typeof import('node:crypto') = require('node:crypto');
//* run only when node environment is available (not the edge runtime nor client side)
async function hash(data:string,salt:string,...moreSalt:string[]):Promise<string>
async function hash(...stuff:string[]):Promise<string>{//asynchronous to maintain identical interface to the web API version
    const x=_crypto.createHash('sha256');
    if (stuff.length<2) throw new Error("hash() not given valid salt")
    x.update("".concat(...stuff)+"APPNAME");
    return x.digest('hex');
}
const maxSecRan=2n**48n-1n;
function random(range:bigint):bigint{
    return (range<=maxSecRan)?
        BigInt(_crypto.randomInt(Number(range))):
        _crypto.randomInt(1)?
            random(range/2n):
            range/2n+random(range-(range/2n));
}
export default {hash:hash,random:random};
```

for an example as to how this ends up working the middleware running on edge runtime imports as follows:

```
import './lib/crypto/provideWeb'; //sets up the correct crypto functions to make the auth functions work
import { getValidatedSessionData } from './lib/server_only/auth/login';
```

and the module containing the server actions available to the client imports as follows:

```
'use server'
import './crypto/provideNode'; //! this will break in the edge runtime !
import { signIn,getAccountByID,fakeSalt, getValidatedSessionData } from "@/lib/server_only/auth/login";
```